# get count of duplicate values in a calculated column in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, calculated-column-formula, list-form

I have a sharepoint list with data as below.

```
ID  EN   DE   FR   Val
1   EN1  DE1  FR1   1
1   EN1  DE1  FR1   1
1   EN2  DE2  FR2   2
1   EN2  DE2  FR2   2
1   EN2  DE2  FR2   2
1   EN3  DE3  FR3   3
2   EN1  DE1  FR1   1
2   EN1  DE1  FR1   1
2   EN1  DE1  FR1   1
2   EN2  DE2  FR2   2
2   EN2  DE2  FR2   2
2   EN3  DE3  FR3   3
```

Now in the above list, i want to group by field Val and sort by the group by count
which means the output should be as below for ID=1

```
Val2(3)
Val1(2)
Val3(1)
```

I tried using view, but could not find way to configure the way i want.
So now i am thinking to use calculated field and that field will have the count as below and then group by that calculated field.

```
ID  EN   DE   FR   Val   cal
1   EN1  DE1  FR1   1     2
1   EN1  DE1  FR1   1     2
1   EN2  DE2  FR2   2     3
1   EN2  DE2  FR2   2     3
1   EN2  DE2  FR2   2     3
1   EN3  DE3  FR3   3     1
2   EN1  DE1  FR1   1     3
2   EN1  DE1  FR1   1     3
2   EN1  DE1  FR1   1     3
2   EN2  DE2  FR2   2     2
2   EN2  DE2  FR2   2     2
2   EN3  DE3  FR3   3     1
```

Can you please help how i can achieve this. The main reason for this is , i want to show the items with max count of Val field in another list form.

Thanks in advance,
Usha

Answer (score 0):

We can't short by count value since this is dynamically load based on the Group By field in View.

In addition, we could only use default sort syntax(A,B,C OR 1,2,3) in group by.

[image]